# where can I get llvm-config for windows?

Tags: haskell, llvm

I need llvm-config because I'm trying to use the Haskell module llvm-general. I just installed llvm 3.6 using the windows installer and it does not contain this .exe. Is there somewhere else I can aquire it? Thanks.

Comment: This guy seems to have them pre-built https://github.com/CRogers/LLVM-Windows-Binaries but I would build from source just to be on the safe side

Comment: @Arbus the pre-built Windows binaries are based on LLVM 3.4, so build it locally would be a better option.